# The group algebra decomposition for an abelian variety

Tags: abelian-varieties

I was reading this [paper](https://books.google.cl/books?hl=es&lr=&id=c3alBQAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA43&dq=symmetric%20group%20action%20on%20jacobian&ots=VAN41MOPbd&sig=a1UAwKEofAsau-JA1CaRdmS8dI8&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=symmetric%20group%20action%20on%20jacobian&f=false), and I want to understand the definition of $Fix_{G_k}{\mathcal{W}}$ given in $1.2$.

[image]

I tried to use the formula on a specific example and it did not worked (I think that I did not understand the definition of Fix).

Let $G=S_3$ and the signature $\sigma=(1;3)$. This signature has two possible generating vectors $\mathcal{V}=(\alpha_1,\beta_1,g_1)$ (See [paper](https://books.google.cl/books?hl=es&lr=&id=c3alBQAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA43&dq=symmetric%20group%20action%20on%20jacobian&ots=VAN41MOPbd&sig=a1UAwKEofAsau-JA1CaRdmS8dI8&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=symmetric%20group%20action%20on%20jacobian&f=false)) given by:

\begin{align}
\alpha_1= (1 2), \beta_1=(13), \text{ } g_1=(123)\\
\alpha_1= (1 2), \beta_1=(123),g_1=(123)
\end{align}

On both cases, $G_1$ is the conjugaccy class associated to the cyclic group generated by $g_1=(123)$

Let $\mathcal{W}$ be the irreducible two dimensional representation of $\rho :S_3 \to GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ given by:
\begin{align}
\rho_{(12)}=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 \\
0 & 1  \\
\end{pmatrix} ,
\rho_{(123)}=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 \\
1 & 0  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

I want to know if $Fix_{G_1}{\mathcal{W}}$ means the fixed space for the matrix $\rho_{(123)}$. Since that would mean that is the zero vector. It would follow that $\dim Fix_{G_1}{\mathcal{W}}=0$ and since $\gamma=1$;$\dim \mathcal{W}=2$  and $n_1=3$. Hence $\dim B=3$, but this is not possible since in the paper they proved that if $G=S_3$ and $\sigma=(1;3)$ then the dimension of the factors $B_i$ have dimension $\le 1$.

I tried to do the same for other examples and the same contradiction happens. This is why I think that I did not understand the definition of $Fix_{G_k} \mathcal{W}$ and is probably refering to something different.

Comment: I see no other possible interpretation of $\mathrm{Fix}_{G_k} \mathcal{W}_r$. However, you may be misreading the paper. Their Theorem 2.5 has as an assumption "Hypothesis A", which itself has an assumption $\dim B_i \leq 1$. It does not appear to suggest the converse, i.e. that Hypothesis A must actually hold for that data. (Disclaimer: this is not at all my area.)

Comment: Thanks for your advice but I already know that for that case $dim B_i \le 1$ that's is why I know that I did something wrong